# Combine 2 parts to create a variable in jQuery

Tags: jquery

Not sure about the title.

I have got a list of variables, base name with a number:

```
var answerOption1 = "Agra";
var answerOption2 = "Chicago";
var answerOption3 = "Halong Bay";
```

With that I want to dynamically populate a select list randomly, 12 variables in total with an array of numbers.

```
$('<option>').val(theAnswer).addClass('fieldbox').text(answerOption + arr[i]).appendTo("#answers");
```

As it is its not working, its running into an error because answerOption is undefined, but I need it to include the number from the array before calling the value from the variable

Comment: You'll have to use `eval`, or put the variables into an object (unless they're global).

Comment: Just the first bit.  Eval?  Seriously not.  The simplest answer is JasonP's below, which is what your 2nd suggestion was (roughly).  They're already in an object :)

Comment: *If* they're global. What if that code is in e.g. a document.ready handler?

Comment: Anyway, I definitely agree that `eval` should be avoided, my comment was just stating the options. @Archer

Comment: @bfavaretto Of course - fair enough.  As for the global thing, it probably *is* in a document.ready handler, so creating an object would be a nicer way to go

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use bracket notation to access properties by key:

```
.text(window['answerOption' + arr[i]])
```

I used window since (I think) your variables are global. If they aren't, you'll need to put them in an object, and replace `window` with that object's name.

It might be better to create an actual array of the values:

```
var answerOptions = [
    "Agra",
    "Chicago",
    "Halong Bay"
];

.text(answerOptions[i])
```

Comment: That should be `window["answerOption" + arr[i]]`, since the answerOption part is static, not a variable itself. There's also no guarantee they're globally scoped variables.

Comment: @Jason P

Thanks, the notation worked, I would of considered an array, but I only need 3 options, only 2 of which are from the array and they need to be tied into other functions using the array.

The 3rd option gets its value back from the html, not to mention the 4 languages I am working with.

One of those 23rd hour changes a client wants to make and needs to be done asap, damn things been live for 2 weeks. anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define answerOption  instead of variables and use indexer to access each element of array.

```
var answerOption  = ["Agra", "chicago", "Halong Bay"];
$('<option>').val(theAnswer).addClass('fieldbox').text(answerOption[i]).appendTo("#answers");
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use a single array instead of 12 variables.

```
var answerOptions = [
    "Agra",
    "Chicago",
    "Halong Bay"
];
```

Then populate it however you want pointing to the index of the variable.

```
$('<option>')
    .val(theAnswer)
    .addClass('fieldbox')
    .text(answerOptions[i])  // <----
    .appendTo("#answers");
```

Answer (score 0):

Retrieving from variables when you're generating the name dynamically is possible, but can be tricky depending on their scope. I'd be inclined to create an object with the variables in instead, like so:

```
var variableObject = {
    answerOption1 : "Agra",
    answerOption2 : "Chicago",
    answerOption3 : "Halong Bay"
}
```

Then you'd do:

```
$('<option>').val(theAnswer).addClass('fieldbox').text(variableObject["answerOption" + arr[i]]).appendTo("#answers");
```

Assuming, of course, that `arr[i]` has the dynamic part of the "variable" (it's now actually a property of an object) name, so 1, 2, 3, etc.